# Mysql lookup, update between two tables

Tags: mysql

Having difficulty getting a proper mysql lookup and then to update those records.  I'm having difficulty with the concept of the two separate tables.  Essentially I can find records in one table successfully with:

```
  SELECT email,id  
  FROM  `phplist_user_user` 
  WHERE  `email` LIKE  '%gmail%'
  LIMIT 0 , 30
```

and then seperately:

```
  SELECT userid, value FROM `phplist_user_user_attribute`
```

Now what I can't figure out is how to update value in 'phplist_user_user_attribute' to "gmail.com" for all those records found in the first query.

Comment: Is this the key you are trying to join on? phplist_user_user.id = phplist_user_user_attribute.user_id

Comment: Is there any relation between the two tables `phplist_user_user_attribute` and `phplist_user_user`?

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE phplist_user_user u
JOIN phplist_user_user_attribute a ON u.id = a.userid
SET a.value = 'gmail.com'
WHERE u.email LIKE '%gmail%'
```

Comment: Thank you!  This worked perfectly!  Plus I've learned something in the meantime.

Answer (score 0):

okay apparently it looks like you can not update `phplist_user_user_attribute` table directly.

what you can do is use nested queries.. i.e.
something like
// this is just one way to do it...

```
Update phplist_user_user_attribute
SET your_value = 'foo'
where your_value IN (SELECT your_value  
                     FROM  `phplist_user_user` 
                     WHERE  `email` LIKE  '%gmail%'
                     LIMIT 0 , 30);
```

Comment: Thank you!  This would have worked had I not received a message from MySQL stating that the "IN" feature does not work in my version of MySQL.  mysql -V
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.65, for unknown-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.1